# Bootstrap navbar style not showing up with jade/expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, bootstrap-4, pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css', integrity='sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO', crossorigin='anonymous')
  body
    nav.navbar.navbar-default
      .container-fluid
        .navbar-header
          a.navbar-brand(href='#') NodeAuth
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
          li
            a(href='#') Dashboard
          li
            a(href='/users/register') Register
          li
            a(href='/users/login') Login
          li
            a(href='#') Logout
    block content
  script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', integrity='sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo', crossorigin='anonymous')
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', integrity='sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49', crossorigin='anonymous')
  script(src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js', integrity='sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy', crossorigin='anonymous')
```

I am using the jade render engine and when the page loads it looks like this.
https://gyazo.com/705611129c2d45d931e5bbbe2b5bbff0
I inspect the page/view source and see no errors and that the bootstrap style sheets are loading correctly yet there is no "navbar" bootstrap styling on my page.

What is going on?

Comment: Make sure to read docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ i see you don't use same classes as in the example shown in the link

Comment: Please don't post a link to your website.  Instead, use a screen capture and upload the image, which helps future users of this site see the issue clearly.  Your site will change over time and people here will be left scratching their heads wondering what your issue really was.